# Пункт меню с вложенным списком не остается активным

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Приветствую!
Есть меню. У одного пункта этого меню есть вложенный список. Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на элементы этого вложенного списка, основной пункт этого списка оставался активным (то есть его цвет оставался таким же, как и при наведении просто на этот пункт)?

Тобишь, хочу добиться такого же результата, как на фото.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно чтобы ваш `.dropdown` класс, с выпадающим меню, был ребенком для элемента у которого описан hover-эффект. Например:

```css
ul > li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block
}

.dropdown {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: -40px;
}
nav > ul > li:hover { /* Элемент меню с подсветкой цвета */
color: red;       /* Для .first */
}
nav > ul > li:hover .dropdown { /* Показываем выпадающее меню */
display: block;
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul li {
color: #000000; /* Для .second отменяем изменения цвета li на ховер родителя */
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul li:hover {
color: red;       /* Для .second делаем ховер */
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul class="first">
 <li>Home</li>
 <li>My Blogs 
  <div class="dropdown">
   <ul class="second">
    <li>Blog 1</li>
    <li>Blog 2</li>
    <li>Blog 3</li>
    <li>Blog 4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>Benefits</li>
 <li>Contacts</li>
 <li>About</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо большое!

Comment: Прошу прощение, не могли бы вы, в своем примере, ul и li дать классы, чтобы я смог понять последние две строки кода css. Не понимаю, где что идет

Comment: Оставил пояснения для какого элемента отменяются стили